# Unable to stretch zero rectange in Piccolo2D?

Tags: java, piccolo

Why isn't first and third rectangle appear in the sample below?

Looks like rectangle is broken once it has zero size.

```
package tests.piccolo;

import org.piccolo2d.extras.PFrame;
import org.piccolo2d.nodes.PPath;

public class Try_EmptyRectangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new PFrame() {

            @Override
            public void initialize() {

                PPath rect1 = PPath.createRectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
                PPath rect2 = PPath.createRectangle(0, 100, 1, 1);
                PPath rect3 = PPath.createRectangle(0, 200, 1, 1);

                getCanvas().getLayer().addChild(rect1);
                getCanvas().getLayer().addChild(rect2);


                rect1.setWidth(50);
                rect1.setHeight(50);

                rect2.setWidth(50);
                rect2.setHeight(50);

                rect3.setWidth(0);
                rect3.setHeight(0);
                rect3.setWidth(50);
                rect3.setHeight(50);


            }



        };

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug. `PPath` internally wraps `GeneralPath`. `PPath.createRectangle(0, 0, 0, 0)` initializes `GeneralPath` to a zero size rectangle shape. Then changing `PPath` width/height triggers the bounds change. `PPath` overrides `internalUpdateBounds()` in order to scale the path to fit into the specified bounds. There seem to be a problem with zero sized path:

```
protected void internalUpdateBounds(final double x, final double y, final double width, final double height) {
    final Rectangle2D pathBounds = path.getBounds2D();
    ...
    final double scaleX;
    if (adjustedWidth == 0 || pathBounds.getWidth() == 0) {
            scaleX = 1;
    }
    ...
    final double scaleY;
    if (adjustedHeight == 0 || pathBounds.getHeight() == 0) {
         scaleY = 1;
    }
    ...
    TEMP_TRANSFORM.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
    ...
    path.transform(TEMP_TRANSFORM);
}
```

*scaleX* and *scaleY* are always 1. So the *path* is actually never scaled and remains zero size.